# How to rename android assets recursively and replace dash for underscore

Tags: android, bash, drawable, android-drawable, file-rename

I have some assets that my designer have created, he branched them correctly making all dpi's match their directories so I was happy because I didn't had to copy those files to each subfolder but when I checked out their names they had dashes in the filenames, which made android compiler to fail.

So how I can make a bash script to rename all files below drawable-*, to the same file name but replacing dashes with underscores?

Example:

Convert this :

```
drawable-hdpi/
    my-icon.png
    my-icon-2.png
drawable-xhdpi/
    my-icon.png
    my-icon-2.png
drawable-xxhdpi/
    my-icon.png
    my-icon-2.png
```

To this:

```
drawable-hdpi/
    my_icon.png
    my_icon_2.png
drawable-xhdpi/
    my_icon.png
    my_icon_2.png
drawable-xxhdpi/
    my_icon.png
    my_icon_2.png
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [Bash FAQ 30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030) which discusses this subject in detail, along with provided examples.

Regarding your solution:

- Please note that by convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
              variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.
- "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and every expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. See
  [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), [Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments) and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words.

## TL;DR

```
find /paths/to/drawable/dirs -type f -name '*-*' -print0 \
| while read -rd '' f; do
    # File's path.
    p="${f%/*}"
    # File's base-name.
    f1="${f##*/}"
    # Lower-cased base-name.
    f1="${f1,,}"
    # Rename.
    echo mv "$f" "$p/${f1//-/_}"
  done
```

NOTE: The `echo` command is there on purpose, so that you won't accidently damage your files. Remove it when you're sure it is going to do what it is supposed to.

Comment: Your Solution is by far more elegant thnx

Answer (score 4):

Not really a bash solution, but you can use the `rename` utility from Larry Wall:

```
rename -n 's#(?>\G(?!^)|.*/)[^-]*\K-#_#g' ./pathto/drawable-*/*
```

`-n` is to perform a test, when you are sure remove it.

Answer (score 1):

After researched a bit and reading couple of man pages, I have created a simple script that achieved what I wanted, here is the gist [normalize_assets_script](https://gist.github.com/eefret/8681652fb037b7b5a566)

Will also paste it here:

```
for f in drawable-*/*; do 
    MYDIR=$(dirname $f) # Obtaining dirname
    MYFILE=$(basename $f) # Obtaining filename
    SUB=`echo $MYFILE | sed 's/-/_/g' | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` # Replacing "-" in filename for "_" plus making lowercase
    echo "Moving File $MYDIR/$MYFILE -> $MYDIR/$SUB" #printing info to double check
    mv $MYDIR/$MYFILE $MYDIR/$SUB #moving old file to new file (need sudo)
done
```